# .htaccess redirect not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

A really strange issue. I have some .htaccess 301 redirects that are not working and some that are. They're in the same file, on the same server.

Here's one that works:

```
RewriteRule ^Email-2 Email-2.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*Email-2\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)Email-2\.php$ http://www.myserver.com/myfolder/Email-2$1 [R=301,L]
```

And here's one that doesn't work...

```
RewriteRule ^finance-step2 finance-step2.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*finance-step2\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)finance-step2\.php$ http://www.myserver.com/myfolder/finance-step2$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have 30+ of these redirects, and the only ones that don't work seem to be the -step2, -step3, etc. All the other ones do.

I used Live HTTP Headers in Firefox and it seems that Apache is simply not sending the 301 code with the ones that don't work, but it IS sending the 301 on the ones that do.

I'm pretty savvy with .htaccess and regex, but this one has me stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: Strange, I tried the rules that isn't working locally and they works fine for me. Try to create a new .htaccess file and just use the rules that isn't working.

Comment: Could you please post all your redirections, so that (1) we may quickly guess where the problem actually comes from (it doesn't look like it's coming from those rules) (2) optimise them because I'm pretty sure they've been quickly made and they could be a lot shorter

Comment: Can you give examples of which URLs work: start and final redirection, and which don't: start and what should be the final redirection? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

May I ask you to do some optimization like:
And what was the `HTTP/` at the end of the `RewriteCond`? I've removed it:

```
RewriteRule ^(Email-2|finance-step2) $1.php [QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*(Email-2|finance-step2)\.php
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)(Email-2|finance-step2)\.php$ http://www.myserver.com/myfolder/$2$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

One thing that is really strange: you first redirect `aa` to `aa.php` then you redirect `aa.php` to `http://www.myserver.com/myfolder/aa`. So what was the point of adding `.php`?

Tell me if this works